# Regular Expression Quantifiers

Tags: javascript, regex

I thought this would have been an "no-brainer" addition to my regEx, but of course I was proven wrong...

My current regEx returns true if the string is a symbol (-, $, +, =, (, ), {, }):

```
(/^[-$+)(}{]$/).test(token);
```

I want to add two symbols to the regEx, the assignment operator (=), and the equality operator (==).  My intuition guided me to do something along the lines of to return true if there exists a token with one or two '=':

```
(/^[-$+)(}{]|(=){1,2}$/).test(token);
```

but yet if the actual token is `(/^[-$+)(}{]|(=){1,2}$/).test("===")` true is returned.

Can someone shed some light on my regEx shortcomings?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of operator precedence, the or branches include the start (`^`) and end (`$`) zero-width matches. To catch = or ==, you'd have to use:

```
(/^([-$+)(}{]|={1,2})$/).test(token);
```

Comment: interesting, so the entire expression just had to be enclosed in one group?

Comment: Yes, otherwise your start (`^`) and end (`$`) zero-width matches are included in the or (`|`).

Comment: Where in the question was there a group or quantifier in a character class? It seems you have a correct answer but an incorrect reason.

Comment: Ah, fair point, misread the OP's regex. The downside to "sparse syntax". Editing.

Answer (score 6):

You've run into a subtle operator precedence problem.

> ```
> /^[-$+)(}{]|(=){1,2}$/
> ```

`^` and `$` bind more tightly than `|`, so this is equivalent to

```
/(?:^[\-$+)(}{])|(?:={1,2}$)/
```

instead of what you probably want which is to have `^...$` enclose the `|`:

```
/^(?:[\-$+)(}{]|={1,2})$/
```

or simplified

```
/^(?:[\-$+(){}]|==?)$/
```

---

```
/^(?:[\-$+(){}]|==?)$/.test("===") === false;
/^(?:[\-$+(){}]|==?)$/.test("()")  === false;
/^(?:[\-$+(){}]|==?)$/.test("=")   === true;
/^(?:[\-$+(){}]|==?)$/.test("==")  === true;
/^(?:[\-$+(){}]|==?)$/.test("(")   === true;
```

---

## Digression on capturing vs non-capturing parentheses

I prefer `(?:...)` to `(...)` unless I actually want to capture content because, although `(?:...)` is more verbose, it has fewer subtle effects on code that uses the regular expression.

Some problems with using capturing groups when you don't intend to capture content include:

1. changing the numbering of existing groups since JS doesn't have named groups,
2. using an operator with more effects than I need can confuse a maintainer into thinking I'm capturing content for a reason,
3. changing the behavior of a distant `exec` loop,
   (This is mostly a problem with perlish global matches like `@foo = $str =~ /(foo(bar))/g`
   but every once in a while you'll see JS code doing something similar)
4. changing the behavior of a (possibly variadic) replacer function defined elsewhere like

   ```
   newStr = oldStr.replace(
       regexDefinedEarlier,
       function (var_args) {
         return [].slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.length - 2).join('');
       });
   ```

Comment: I would like to know the same thing, why use that when Adrian's answer simply added parenthesis around the entire expression.

Comment: @TedHopp and Joey, please see the digression I added to my answer.  In short, I use `(?:...)` so that I tread softly when maintaining code, and try to send as few mixed signals to later maintainers as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the digression. It makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

Use this regex:

```
(/^(?:[-$+)(}{]|={1,2})$/).test(token);
```

If you are using anchors `^` (start input ) or `$` (end input) before & after pipe (OR for regex) you must enclose LHS and RHS of `|` in bracket to group it so that `^` or `$` are applicable for whole regex inside the brackets.

Comment: Oh I didn't bother at all :) IMHO `?:` is intended for situations like this when there is a need to group but at the same time there is no need to capture.

Comment: I know what it does. The question was why did you suggest using it for OP's problem? It complicates the regex and doesn't seem to save anything. (Since all capture groups are ignored, there's no need to distinguish between capture groups and non-capture groups.)

Comment: Oh trust me I very well realize that you know it well :) As I said that I used it because there was no need to capture the group and that's precisely the purpose of the `?:`

Answer (score 1):

. . The problem with your Regex is simple: the "^" (starts with) is on the left side of the "pipe", and the "$" (ends with) on the right side. They are only being applied to that part of the Regex, like this:

```
^[-$+)(}{]
OR
(=){1,2}$
```

. . So, you're saying `"_starts with one of these chars_ or _ends with one or two equal signs_"`, got it?

. . What you want is to put a group so that the "alternation" (pipe) only applies to its contents, like this:

```
^([-$+)(}{]|={1,2})$
```

. . Now you're saying: `"the text is made of either of _this list of chars_ or _one or two equal signs_"`.

. Amplexos.